# how to escape at sign (@) in groovy gpath

Tags: java, groovy, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a very specific use case while using rest-assured for testing REST API.
I would like to retrieve a value of '@odata.type' from following JSON response;

```
{
 "value": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#example.type1.",
                ...
             },
             {
                "@odata.type": "#example.type1.",
                ...
             },
            ...
          ]
      }
```

I tried something likle

> get(/path).then().body("value.@odata.type",hasItems("expected_velue"));

but end up getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "null" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function
...
```

How can I escape `@odata.type` so that it will be treated as a single attribute to retrieve its value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried get(/path).then().body("value.\u0040odata\u002Etype",hasItems("expected_velue"));
unicode for @ - \u0040
unicode for  .   -  \u002E
but I got this error:
JSON path value.@odata.type doesn't match.
Expected: (a collection containing "expected_velue")
  Actual: []